# Add the web service reference but cannot see it in object browser and the client class is not generated

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, wcf

I was trying to add some wcf services to my console app in VS Express 2013. I added all services to Web References successfully. For some services from the third party, I can see them in Object Browser and the client class was generated. For services I created, I cannot see them in Object Browser and the client classes were not generated. I read these (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d2bc41df-20ee-4fc1-9807-1cd21dee37f6/can-add-web-service-reference-but-cannot-see-it-in-object-browser-or-use-it and [Why, when adding a service reference in VS2010, is the client class not generated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196355/why-when-adding-a-service-reference-in-vs2010-is-the-client-class-not-generate)) and other posts but still cannot make it work. Here are the codes for the problematic service:

IFileProviderService.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace MyServices
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IFileProviderService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/AppInstaller/{userID}/{fileName}/{os}")]
        Stream AppInstaller(string userID, string fileName, string os);
    }
}
```

FileProviderService.svc.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;

namespace MyServices
{
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode =     AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class FileProviderService : IFileProviderService
    {
        public Stream AppInstaller(string userID, string fileName, string os)
        {
        ......

        }
    }
}
```

Reference.cs

```
#pragma warning disable 1591

namespace ServiceTest.MyFileProviderService {

}

#pragma warning restore 1591
```

This service is running and working properly.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was fixed. It turns out the service has to be 'basicHttpBinding'in order to be accessible from the client. See [Can't get WCF service's operations list with Web Service Studio client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760353/cant-get-wcf-services-operations-list-with-web-service-studio-client?rq=1)